# Magento cron only missed and skipped

Tags: magento, cron

I'm using module **AOE Schedule**r as an aid

```
Cpanel cron = */5 * * * * /bin/sh -f /home/cpanel_user/public_html/cron.sh
```

I tried many and many cron commands, but this one works because it returns after a missed or skipped time

[image: example of cron missed and skipped]

Cron config in magento:

[image: magento cron config]

I do not think the solution, I am days with this, it does not generate error, it does not have cron log, in the system log and exception not appears anything, is there any solution?

**Shared hostgator server**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using the default Magento cron.

If you want the AOE Scheduler to work you need to use the scheduler's cron instead - e.g.:

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/sh -f /home/cpanel_user/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh
```

FYI - the "heartbeat" task is a very lightweight cron job that runs every time, simply reporting that the scheduler is running. If your message is showing you that the heartbeat couldn't be found it likely means either that your cron isn't configured correctly, or there's a lock in place. You can try removing `var/locks` and the scheduler's lock which normally lives in `/tmp` if this is the case.

Comment: With scheduler_cron.sh is only pending eternally until clearing the historico, I wanted to know how to fix missed and skipped =(

Comment: You can flush the schedule from the scheduler admin interface, or from the command line